# if else statement is not able to parsed by GroovyClassLoader with if enter between if and condition start bracket

Tags: groovy

i developing one simple application and using groovy script

i am not able to parse if else Satement if enter between if and else .

E.G:

below is not working script :

```
def execute(){
    if 
      (condition 1)         
         {

        }

    else if 
      (condition 2)
      {

      }
}
```

working script :

```
if(condition 1)
         {

        }

    else if  (condition 2)
      {

      }
}
```

if i remove enter from if and condition start bracket then it is working fine.

can any one suggest me the workarround for this ?

Error :

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script1512377268429238880887.groovy: 48: expecting '(', found "" @ line 48, column 8.
       if 
          ^

1 error

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: why would you put a new line between `if` and the condition?

Comment: Seems that you have unmatched brackets in both code blocks.

Comment: Error :
 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script1512377268429238880887.groovy: 48: expecting '(', found '<newline>' @ line 48, column 8.
       if 
          ^

1 error

Answer (score 0):

Well, the syntax simply is invalid, what workaround are you after?

Either do not use newline between the if and the condition, or escape the newline character by using

```
if \
  (condition 1)         
     {

    }

else if \
  (condition 2)
  {

  }
```